# Link doesn't stay on the top of the screen with the image

Tags: css, hyperlink, fixed

I have a website. And a logo which is always on the top of the screen. When you scroll down is still there, the top of the screen, you still see it. This is fine. On the top the logo image have a link, but when you scroll down, you lose it. I want the link to go with the image. I hope i was clear. 
Here is the html:

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="menu">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2" id="logoparent">
            <div id="logo">
                <!--<h3>LOGO</h3>-->
                <a href="#menu" id="logoa"><img src="Logo.png" id="thelogo"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-2 col-md-6 space">
            <!-- empty -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-2 col-md-1 menuitem" id="home">
            <h3><a href="index.php">Home</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-1 menuitem" id="gallery">
            <h3><a href="#uresnyille">Gallery</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-1 menuitem" id="about">
            <h3><a href="#uresnyille1">About</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-1 menuitem" id="contact">
            <h3><a href="#uresnyille2">Contact</a></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the css:

```
#logo{
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 99;
   height: 60px;
   width: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-left: auto !important;
   margin-right: auto !important;
}
#logoa{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}
#thelogo{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#menu{
   position: relative;
   z-index: 5;
}
#content-all{
   position: relative;
   z-index: 5;     /*which is everything under the menu*/
}
```

Comment: As we can see you use the bootstrap framework. The frameworks provides well coded [navigation bars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). You should use them in your code. [Here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-brand-image) you can see how to implement an image to those navbars.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to add a link to that logo by itself so when you click to the logo you go to the appropriate link, always if that logo has something to do with the link, otherwise add use nested DOM to style it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all menu tags in main tag and set css style for main tag like this

```
#menu1{
  position: fixed;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  height: 60px;
  width:50px;

}
```

Check this

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y5j1bs3n/1/)